# jQuery check if Cookie Contains Text

Tags: jquery, cookies, contains

Trying to check to see if a cookie contains specific value of text.  Is there a way to do this?  For instance, my current cookies value is 'www.yahoo.com', but this tells me that $.cookie("referrer") is null, when it is actually not:

```
  if ($.cookie('referrer').contains('yahoo')){
     alert('YOU CAME FROM YAHOO!') }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `cookie` returns a string value which does not support `contains` in javascript.  You should use `indexOf`.

Comment: Ok, I only use jQuery but would this be close to what javascript I'm looking for? `if (document.cookie.indexOf("yahoo", referrer)`

Comment: `if ($.cookie('referrer').indexOf('yahoo')>-1){`  because `indexOf` returns the location of the passsed parameter `yahoo` inside the string being called on (your cookie value).

Comment: O perfect I did not know we could use indexOf with jQuery, however, I am still getting the error that it is null: '$.cookie("referrer") is null' when it clearly isn't.

Comment: jQuery **IS** javascript.  Try alerting it, maybe it just is null.

Comment: Disregard, I changed the 'referrer' to a different cookie and it works fine, something must be wrong with the cookie itself, thank you.